# Joomla show content if current article category id is

Tags: php, joomla

i am using joomla 2.5 and i want to show some special text only in those articles which belongs to category id 11.

to get category id i tried:

```
<?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); echo $catid; ?>
```

to check if current category id is  11 and then show special text i used:

```
<?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); if ($catid == 11) {?>SPECIAL TEXT<?php } ?>
```

but it is not working :( text can be seen in all categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement doesn't look right... try this:

```php
<?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); if ($catid == 11) : ?>SPECIAL TEXT<?php endif; ?>
```

See ["Alternative syntax for control structures" on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: thanx, unfortunately special text is invisible even if current article category id is 11. Seems that we need joomla expert :) something is wrong in my code.

Comment: I am sorry, it was my fault, i used wrong category id, now everything is working fine.

Comment: <?php $catid = JRequest::getInt('catid'); if ($catid == 11) {?>SPECIAL TEXT<?php } ?> 

is also working, my mistake was in category id :)